# spring security 3.0 unable to get/process user credentials

Tags: mysql, jdbc, spring-security

Please help me out for the below mentioned scenario....

applicationContext-security.xml

```xml
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
     <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
         users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password FROM myLibrary.user WHERE username=?" />
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

database-end(MySQL)

```sql
CREATE TABLE `myLibrary`.`user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `enabled` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fullName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `password` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
);
```

xml-user

```xml
<user-service>
    <user name="admin" password="amdin" authorities="supervisor, user" />
    <user name="counter1" password="counter1" authorities="user" /> 
</user-service>
```

"dataSource"; values as perfect too...!!! And there is no exception in any logs....which means library integration is perfect. In fact while using XML based user definitions it works great....but in database access it falis.

My login page sticks to the same; i mean login fails. Pls help friends....!!!!

Comment: Are you sure there is no exception. Have you set logging level to debug for spring classes?

Comment: Could you please post the exact output of login fails? And post the security configuration too.

Comment: Thanks... @flash ...sorry...couldn't see your comment....and yes there are **no exceptions** at all and that's creating a confusion...:)

Comment: Raph....the `http-tag'...is mentioned below; <http use-expressions="true"> <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="permitAll" /> <intercept-url pattern="/myLibrary/**" access="isAuthenticated()" /> <form-login login-page='/login.jsp' default-target-url='/myLibrary/home' /><logout logout-success-url='/login.jsp' logout-url='/j_spring_security_logout' /><session-management invalid-session-url='/login.jsp' /></http>.........as you can visualize....as the login fails...it get back to the 'login.jsp'....!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the delay....!!! so the problem is at the table responsible for users and that must have to be **`users`**. And it's running awesome.....!!! thanks friends.....thanks a lot...!!!!

```
<authentication-manager>   <authentication-provider>      <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>   </authentication-provider> </authentication-manager>
```

Before the above xml-lines; make sure the table for the users must have to be **`users`** and also another table **`authorities`** must exists with foreign key to **`users - username`**. Ok..allow me to put the database part too..!!

```
CREATE TABLE `myLibrary`.`users` (     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,       `enabled` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,     `fullName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,     `password` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,     `username` varchar(40) NOT NULL,     PRIMARY KEY (`id`),     UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),     UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)   );

CREATE TABLE `myLibrary`.`authorities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `authority` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_username` (`username`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_username` FOREIGN KEY (`username`) REFERENCES `users` (`username`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ;
```

Please note that; `authorities(allowed)` is not mandatory....it's part of my code..as i want to show the user....all of it's authorities regardless of it's permission to use.

I am using **`hibernate`** and so i am getting **`ID`** field...and off-course it's upto you as fas as it's usability is concerned.

Have a nice day...!!!!

:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the query a bit, because [`JdbcDaoImpl`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) expect 3 parameter:

- username
- password
- enabled

so you need to add `true` as last parameter:

```xml
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, true
       FROM myLibrary.user WHERE username=?" />
```

Unfortunately this is not very well documented in the api, but you should have a look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java) of [`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.0.7.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java)

---

Btw: 
If you use authorities, then you must also specify an `authorities-by-username-query` (except the default one is what you need)

```xml
<jdbc-user-service
   data-source-ref="dataSource"
   users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, true FROM myLibrary.user WHERE username=?"
   authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username,authority from users WHERE username=?"
 />
```

*Of course this is an example, and the query will likely not work for your tables!*

Comment: Thanks Ralph.....i understand your point...but my qi=uestion is without "authorities-by-username-query"....is there any errors in my approach..?????

Comment: BikahSahoo: you are right, I did not read the `xml-user` right. But now the more interesting question is, what is this file for. `jdbc-user-service` will pay no attention to it (as fare as I know)

Comment: well...i want to provide the user credentials to **spring-security** via a **jdbc connectivity**....so that'w why **jdbc-user-service**....!!!! and secondly...the credential will be from **user** table...so that's why **users-by-username-query**.

Comment: @Ralph.....so....forget about the authorities for now.....atleast the user authentication part should work....!!!

Comment: @BikahSahoo: how do you provide/forbid access to the page that is invoked after login (and all resource that are need for this page) to the users, by authroities or by `isAuthenticated()`?

Comment: @Ralph...question not cleared friend....will you please be little explanatory please...!!!

Comment: @Ralph....do you mean to say...beyond 'isAuthenticated()'...how APP will acess the database (user credential)???? if yes....then how come it is working with XMS-values...??? If not....what's wrong????

Comment: I belive I have identified one (hopefully the only one) problem, see my extended answer

Comment: Sorry for the delay....!!! so the problem is at the table responsible for users and that must have to be **users**. And it's running awesome.....!!!   thanks friends.....thanks a lot...!!!!